# "what had she said " vs "what she had said" Which one is correct?

Tags: inversion

I had been deemed "what she had said" is correct sentence. However lately I played some English visual novel games, there was a sentence with strange grammar: "what had she said".

Which one is correct? Or I can use both as correct one?

Comment: Neither one is a sentence, and the grammar is good in both cases. But they're not the same construction.

Comment: What you should really think about is: “I had been deemed”

Comment: "What had she said?" makes sense as a question, not really otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @MikeGraham. I understood.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. So, how can I say it instead?

Comment: In Japanese dictionary called ALC the definition of "deem" is almost same as "think" but a little different nuance to Japanese. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @igar - "Deem" is more like "judge" or "ascribe".  Example sentences would be "The teacher deemed the student's performance acceptable", or "the chef deemed the meat to be overcooked".  You could say "I had been informed 'what she had said' is a correct sentence", or "I thought 'what she had said' was deemed to be a correct sentence"

Comment: Thank you @stevekeiretsu, I understood.